# Trusty 14.04.2 samba 4 windows xp join error

Tags: 14.04, windows-xp, samba4

In the past year I made many installation of ad dc server with samba on ubuntu 14.04 lts server amd64.
Every installation with same (or very similar) configuration with bind backend and level 2003 (the first installation) and then always 2008_R2.
Everything works like a charm, except this time: I cannot join the domain with windows xp pro (x86) clients, with windows 7 client worked perfectly.
Windows xp, during the join, gives me internal server error.
In RSAT, under computers group, I find the client but disabled.
I tried to debug but I found only a message that seems related to kerberos (packet size too long if I remember correctly), so I enable kerberos via TCP on xp client but nothing changed.

At this point I think that there is a bug in the latest version of samba distribuited by ubuntu.
In the last installation I use the latest stable version:

**4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.8**

Before I used:

**4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.7**

And the configurations are the same (it's 10 years I use samba)...
Thank you very much.
Bye

Comment: Hi, yesterday I tried to downgrade to .7 version but I have the same problem, so there's something else, but I don't find anything in samba logs... with debugging set to 3 or 4...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the last samba problems when it acts as DC or a member server are related with the kernel you're running.

For samba 4.0 the kernel 3.2.xxxx was good. For 4.1 you need to use kernel 3.13.xxx.

Try to downgrade the kernel two releases down within the same branch you're running now.

Comment: Could you provide a source for thaa+t information please

Comment: I suffered that problems in my servers. Same samba configuration with samba 4.0 worked perfectly with kernel 3.2, after upgrade to 3.13 some client computers cannot connect to the samba shares. After a downgrade to kernel 3.2 all worked perfectly as before.